# What movie features a soldier on a train trying to stop it blowing up?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a movie which sounds like this:

- This soldier dies in a US war (I think)
- The soldier believes he is still alive, but had actually died two/three months ago
- He keeps on reliving these same memories all over again
- The setting is on a train
- He is actually on a mission to discover who blew up this train
- He always meets this woman
- In the end he finds out that he is actually being used to relive this other persons last memory and was sent to keep on reliving this persons memory's until he can find the person who blew up the train
- Before he decides to truly die, he relives this guys memory's one last time to save this woman he met

After this I cannot remember anything else as I never got to see the ending. I would really love it if you could help me identify this movie.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I think you are referring to the movie [*Source Code*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0945513/).

Comment: Has it got a train in it? I remember watching it in school maybe last year or so. Wait, I wqill just google search. :)

Comment: @MiharuDante - Yes, the protagonist is on a train.

Comment: Sorry, I was just watching the trailer. Seems like the one.

Comment: @Richard- I was just watching that trailer on another tab before you edited the question. xD

Comment: isn't this a fairly new movie ?

Comment: Nothing like trailers that give away the entire plot.  Glad I saw the movie without first seeing the trailer.

Comment: @ryan: A question that's easily answered by checking IMDB.

Comment: Hmmm, 92% fresh according to [Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/source_code).  I may have to check it out.